# What port is my USB device connected to?

Tags: usb, port

The command :

```
 ioreg -p IOUSB -l -b | grep -E "@|PortNum|USB Serial Number"
```

gives :

```
 o USB 2.0 Hub@14200000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000311c8, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 14>
    {
      "sessionID" = 28933243797551
      "iManufacturer" = 0
      "bNumConfigurations" = 1
      "idProduct" = 1025
      "bcdDevice" = 256
      "Bus Power Available" = 500
      "USB Address" = 9
      "bMaxPacketSize0" = 64
      "iProduct" = 1
      "iSerialNumber" = 0
      "bDeviceClass" = 9
      "Built-In" = No
      "locationID" = 337641472
      "bDeviceSubClass" = 0
      "bcdUSB" = 512
      "USB Product Name" = "USB 2.0 Hub"
      "PortNum" = 2
      "non-removable" = "no"
      "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"9dc7b780-9ec0-11d4-a54f-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
      "bDeviceProtocol" = 1
      "IOUserClientClass" = "IOUSBDeviceUserClientV2"
      "IOPowerManagement" = {"DevicePowerState"=0,"CurrentPowerState"=3,"CapabilityFlags"=65536,"MaxPowerState"=4,"DriverPowerState"=3}
      "Device Speed" = 2
      "idVendor" = 6720
      "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
      "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBDevice"
    }
```

This is the exact device. I am however having trouble figuring out the port name in the "tty" system.

Comment: A hub has no port name in the tty system.

Comment: The Hub is connected to with a USB to serial which connects it a device. I am trying to open the port to that device for communication

Comment: So how do I find the serial port name ?